# Google Analytics: Easy way to report on users who visit Page A and Page B in the same session?

Tags: google-analytics, web-analytics, visitor-pattern

I know about all the new GA reports like Visitor Flow, goal tracking, etc, but is there an easy way to track users visit PageA and PageB in the same session?  I don't care what path they took or if one was an exit page or an entrance page.  I simply want to know the amount of visitors who visited both PageA and PageB at some point in the session (even if they visited Page C, Page D, and Page E before, between, or after).

Can this be done in a Custom Report somehow, which would be preferable?  If I need to use regular expressions that's fine as well.  Or do I perhaps need to set up a filtered profile?

Thank you very much in advance!

Glenn

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just create an Advanced Segment (click on "Advanced Segments" up on top under the "standard reports" tab, then on "create new segment" on the right).

The conditions for this segment:

include page 1 
AND 
include page 2

Done.

---

Link to Google's [Advanced Segment Documentation](http://support.google.com/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1033017)

Comment: thanks for the answer.  Much simpler than I had anticipated!  Much appreciated.  I always seem to forget the simple aspects of GA.